# How to prevent Jsoup from unescaping html?

Tags: html, jsoup, html-escape-characters

I am parsing an html string with Jsoup in order to extract just the text, and want to get  the exact text, but when I parse strings that include escaped chars Jsoup unescapes them.
For example - if I parse

`<p>Let&#39;s try</p>`

Jsoup returns

`<p>Let's try</p>`

I searched extensively for a solution and tried using the `doc.outputSettings` with different options of `charset` and `escapeMode`, but couldn't get Jsoup to not escape the html special chars

Comment: Why does it matter? The HTML has exactly the same meaning either way.

Comment: After extracting the text I am running some manipulations on it, then I want to find and replace in the original string. Because of the unescaping I can't find the extracted text

Answer (score 0):

Judging from [this comment](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/56#issuecomment-257133693) and the current [EscapeMode documentation](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Entities.EscapeMode.html), this is not possible with Jsoup.

> I'm never going to implement EscapeMode.none as it only leads to broken parse trees.